# Does the word "out" carry sexual-minority flavour?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, figurative, sexual-minorities

My NGO and partners are producing a feature film about Russian speakers in the world, and to explain its point as bias-breaking, we came up with the name ***out***, that's nicely expanded in the slogan as *out* of politics, *out* of bias, *out* of propaganda.

Today a colleague from the US brought to my attention that *out* has strong sexual minority connotations. Having a reasonably good command of English I disagree, but then I thought I need another opinion. We  just started crowd-funding for it and wouldn't like to be looking funny. The context may be seen at http://outfilm.cmpip.org. Advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Call it вне - Then you can explain it like you just did

Comment: that's the word we use in the Russian version of the slogan, but it's weird in Russian when used alone, so we use OUT for the name even in the Russian version.

Comment: "Today a colleague from the US brought to my attention that out has strong sexual minority connotations" - sure, of course it does (certainly in the US). "Having a reasonably good command of English I disagree" .. you're wrong on this one.  Ask anyone in the US.  "Out" would be a typical name for say a homosexual-oriented magazine (I think there might be such a title already??)

Comment: I tried searching for LGBT film titles with the word OUT in them in my coffee break. Not so easy at work, so I stopped.

Comment: @mplungjan, yeah, same for my link - gotta bury that in my browsing history! lol!

Comment: aren't u guys supposed to be living in democratic countries... oh man the next film we do is going to be about people who were wrongly stereotyped by the nature of websites they visit from their office :)) lol :)) I appreciate both your courage and help! :)

Comment: How about *Outside*? There is another word, *without*, which technically is the opposite of *within*, ie on the outside of something, though these days it tends to mean *not having*. Many a schoolchild has been puzzled by the hymn *There is a green hill far away/Without a city wall*.

Comment: I have never seen 'out' used in this way, admittedly I speak British English... But perhaps this is an American only thing? Or perhaps I have just not heard it.

Comment: @Vality, which meaning are you referring too? I'm thinking this might be an US thing, please cheer me up if you can :) The co-production is European so maybe I can still use it

Comment: @Vality This is definitely BrE too. Sorry Igor.

Comment: @Mynamite hmn, I am a touch surprised by that. I do know that the term "coming out" can have such an implication, but I have never seem the word out alone used in such a way, perhaps some may but at least in my experience I have not seem it.

Comment: @Vality this is just [one example](http://www.voice-online.co.uk/article/out-and-proud) of many.

Comment: If you called it "Getting Out" or "Running Out", as in Getting out of Politics, Running out of Propaganda, then you wouldn't have a problem.  Out by itself has come to have the association with the LGBT community.  It does work in other contexts with accompanying words though, unlike gay, queer, tea-bag, etc.  Those words used to have many innocuous meanings, but now are mostly uni-taskers.

Comment: @Mynamite I've never heard 'out' used to mean that without 'closet' in the same sentence though? Admittedly though I don't run in those circles.. or.. out of them.. or whatever!

Comment: @Mynamite +1 for Without though. 'Without the house' another example (which literally means 'outside' per your other). Without politics/without bias/without propaganda all sound perfectly natural - and tbh better than 'out' even *without* other meaning.

Comment: As a native speaker I don't thing your problem is so much the possible (LBGT etc) connotations of the word 'out'- it's more that 'Out' on its own doesn't express much of anything else. And 'out of politics', 'out of bias' don't carry a clear meaning either. Do you mean 'without'?  'Beyond'? 'Above'? Would 'No [Limits or something] work better?

Comment: I guess I'll have to give up the "good command of English" oppinion :) We'll be reconsidering the title even though it's pretty difficult at this stage... Thanks everyone for the amazing discussion ;)

Comment: Yea absolutely if I saw a movie called "Out" that was a documentary, I'd assume it's about LGBT people

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I imagine that your US colleague was referring to the expression, *"out"*, used when a LGBT (lesbian, gay, bi-sexual, trans-sexual) person goes public with their alternate-lifestyle orientation.  It's referred to as *"[coming out of the closet](http://gaylife.about.com/od/comingout/u/howtocomeout.htm)"*, and has been morphed into *"outing"* or *"outed"* when it's done to someone by someone else:

> "He was *outed* by his disgruntled ex-lover."
>
> "She was angered by the newspaper's *outing* of her lesbian affair."

Comment: thanks Kristina. I understand what he was referring to, but the question is whether the word OUT by itself, and in particular in the context presented in the question, raises such connotations.

Comment: To me it would. I am neither LGBT nor native English speaker but I would still expect it to be about _coming out_ or outing someone

Comment: @IgorR, as a AmE native speaker, in the context of today's social environment, if I saw something called "OUT", my first assumption would be that it was about someone's sexual orientation being exposed.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: Even if it were in a baseball context?

Comment: @Dan - I know a LOT less about Baseball than I know about LGBT - I would assume LGBT unless it had innings and stuff surrounding it

Comment: @Dan, if I saw an ad that had a baseball with the word "OUT" superimposed on it, I still think my first thought might be that it's about a gay baseball player.  Now if it said, "You're Out!", given the additional context of a baseball expression, that would be different. :-)

Comment: We'll have a gay ole time :)

Comment: Now it sounds more specific. Can't just use words in their original meaning anymore these days it seems. :) Thanks everyone for sharing, we'll be reviewing the name I guess... Although it's almost too late now.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: "outing" something (or someone) isn't specific to homosexuality - it refers to revealing a secret about that person.  "coming out" similarly refers to revealing one's own secret.  Using the phrase in any unusual way is liable to turn it into innuendo, though.  (I personally wouldn't see the word "out" as referring to homosexuality unless a closet was also mentioned.)

Comment: Right, you are, @Brilliand.  Moreover, I'd have to dig into the ngrams to prove it, but I suspect that the general usage of "out" and "outing" came after "coming out of the closet" got shortened to "coming out" or just "out".

Comment: Not just about others, I (and acquaintances) also use phrases like "I'm not out at work" or "I'm out to my family" and so on.

Comment: when it's used as a verb i would **never** assume "out" is related to homosexuality. when it's used as an adjective, i would pretty much **always** assume it refers to homosexuality. "outing someone" definitely does not automatically make me think of homosexuality—more context is required.

Comment: @sgroves: I find the opposite.  When used as an adjective, like "he is out", it doesn't automatically imply gayness to me.  (Without further context, he's just not here.)  But when it's used as a verb, that's the first place my mind goes.

Answer (score 17):

The connotation is not just LGBT-related. You can come out as a bronie. You can be outed as a spy.

However, your friend is right. If your documentary is not about LGBT people coming out of the closet, then it is a bad choice for a title if your documentary is meant to play in US and EU.

For example, this hugely popular song works for all kinds of coming out, but it is nevertheless seen as an LGBT anthem:

I’m Coming Out — Diana Ross
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_Coming_Out

… so even if your documentary is about coming out as a Russian speaker, people will assume at first that it is about coming out as LGBT.

Also, one of the most popular LGBT magazines of the past 20+ years is called “Out:”

Out Magazine
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_(magazine)

The reason people hear an LGBT connotation is that we are 40+ years into a massive worldwide social movement that encourages LGBT people not to “stay in the closet,” but rather to “come out” and gain strength in numbers to resist heterosexual violence and oppression. Once you have “come out,” you are said to be “out.” You may be referred to as an “out lesbian.” You might know someone is LGBT, but you might ask someone else, “is he out?” You might be careful not to accidentally “out” someone who is in the closet, because by doing so you may get them fired, evicted, beaten, or killed by heterosexuals.

My understanding is that Russia is many years behind US and EU with regards to LGBT rights, so you may not hear your title in the same way that people in US and EU might hear it. But later down the road, you may hear it that way and personally regret the title.

But separate from the LGBT-related connotation, I really don’t understand your title and tag line, and I’m British and US American. Do you mean “[Coming] Out” or “[Getting] Out” or “[Run] Out” or “[With]out” or “Out[side]?” You may have to be more explicit because we don’t know as much about the project as of course you do. You may need to be over-informative in your own eyes, because all of your potential viewers are under-informed.

I recommend you consider creating a new title for your documentary. “Out” not only says too much about something unrelated, it seems to me that it doesn’t say enough about the actual work. A good title can be really hard, but it’s so important. It’s a handle that your viewers can use to pull your work closer to them. With your source material, it seems to me that you have a lot of culture and creativity to draw from, so I feel like there is a better title waiting for you in the aether if you continue to chase it.

Comment: Kristina's answer is short and to the point, but I definitely agree with the latter half of this answer.  Even reading the description in the question, I can't figure out what "out" is supposed to be referring to.  If the movie about breaking stereotypes, then that's definitely the wrong word to use...

Comment: In addition to _Out_ the magazines (there are several), there are also things like _OutGames_ (the LGBT Olympics), _Out_ (LGBT film festival), _OUT_ (South African LGBT association), the _AllOut_ campaign, and many, many, many more.

Answer (score 11):

I cannot see the word ***OUT*** without thinking outing/coming out

It does by the way not sound very idiomatic to say *out of bias, out of borders, out of propaganda*

***Apart***, ***Beyond***, ***Besides*** even ***Without*** sounds better to me - [more here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/without)

Comment: when you say "not very idiomatic" does it mean hard to understand or just not typical use? can it be seen as a kind of poetic form?

Comment: It doesn't sound like something a native speaker would say, even poetically.

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is worse than useless

Comment: Looks like a drive-by downvoting @mplungjan!  Both answers and the question got downvoted.  grr!

Comment: Indeed "out of propaganda" sounds like you've "run out". As in your had 10 ideas for propaganda but now you've used those and you're "out of propaganda" and will have to develop some real policies